# Halogens and the free energy of activation in a resonant benzene system

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

If we look at the right-hand-side table here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_equation, we notice something particular.  It appears that the free energy of activation (for example, measured in terms of the acidicity of a carboxyl group on a benzene ring), and with respect to substituents in the para- position on the benzene ring, increases as one moves down column 17 on the periodic table.

Why is this happening?  Shouldn't we expect the opposite to be true?  Consider that, as we travel down column 17 corresponding to the halogens, electronegativity decreases and the probability of resonance contributions via pi-bonding should increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resonance between a carbon and a halogen atom decreases as we move down the series $\ce{F, Cl, Br, I}$.  This is because overlap is most effective between orbitals of the same size.  Therefor, carbon-fluorine overlap, both involving $\ce{2p-2p}$ orbitals should be much stronger than carbon $\ce{2p}$ orbital overlap with the $\ce{3p, 4p, etc_{.}}$ orbitals in the larger halogens.  Consequently carbon-halogen resonance becomes less significant as we move down the halogen series.  If we now consider that 1) the resonance and inductive effects for the *para*-halogens are in opposition to each other (tend to counteract each other) and 2) the resonance effect decreases as we move down the halogen series, then the order of halogens in the Table you mentioned makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to make sense to me.  However, I don't understand your last point.  How does (1) help to explain the table ordering?  It's exactly contrary to what you would expect from inductive effects.  This just seems to mean that resonance effects dominate for halogens (with the one exception of Iodine in the meta- position, which could be due to stereochemical complications)?

Comment: The values for the meta-substituents should be caused primarily by inductive effects.  Looking at the Table, we see that they are all very close, within 0.06 units of one another.  We would expect the para-substituents to display a similarly close grouping for the inductive effect, just diminished somewhat due to greater through-bond distance.  If we overlay a decreasing resonance effect as we move down the halogen group, on to a fairly constant inductive effect, we get the observed pattern for the para-substituents.

Comment: Sorry, I've accepted your answer, and it is helpful (I was away from my computer for awhile).  However, just to follow up, my point is that the inductive effect shouldn't be approximately constant, right?  Fluorine has an electronegativity of 3.98, chlorine 3.16, bromine 2.96, iodine 2.66, astatine 2.2, and so forth.  So the trend for inductive contributions runs contrary to the trend for resonance contributions.

Comment: The meta inductive effect runs (roughly) counter to the electronegativity scale. You'd expect the inductive and resonance effects to be in opposition.  The resonance effect works to pump substituent electrons in, while the inductive effect would take electrons out.